# How to get the context of block in Moodle

Tags: moodle

In **Moodle** `activity` `context` is get as:

```
$context = context_module::instance($courseid);
```

similarly in **Moodle** `block` how can I get the `context`?

I try `$context = context_block::instance($courseid);`.

But in `block_xxx.php`,  `$this->context->id` gives different value.

**Moodle version 2.9.1**

Answer (score 0):

To get the context of a block you need to know the block instance ID.

```
context_block::instance($instance->id);
```

I don't think this is necessarily easy to do outside your `block_xxx.php`, maybe you could describe your usecase.